# MathJax not rendering and only showing the latex code

Tags: bug, mathjax

it is very old problem and here is a screenshot of the problem
[image: m]

Comment: Try private mode, try disabling whatever add-ons you have, try another browser.

Comment: I don't use any addon and i switched from firedox to chrome for the same problem

Comment: Please anyone reply